# EmberJS, String interpolation in a helper call

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I have this helper call in my template:

```
{{my-helper id='myID'}}
```

And I want to make the `id` param value a bit more dynamic, for example:

```
{{#each charts as |chart|}}
  {{my-helper id='chart' + chart.id}}
{{/each}}
```

How I can I use string interpolation and concatenation to create a value for a param in a helper call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [concat](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat) helper to do this:

```
{{#each charts as |chart|}}
  {{my-helper id=(concat 'chart' chart.id)}}
{{/each}}
```

It's not [ES2015 String interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), but it will do what you want.